# How to form an array using values present against all the that exists in a json object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, angular

I have a variable that contains a json object. I need to form an array using this variable such that all values present in the json object against all keys should be present in the formed array.

**What I have**

`let obj = {
     "name":"abdus",
     "age":25,
     "present": true
};`

**What I need**

result: `["abdus", 25, true]`

Is there any way to achieve this? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no JSON here. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: See ref for the general case, or else do `[obj.name, obj.age, obj.present]`.